# Name of this property : $x < y$ implies $f(x) < f(y)$

Tags: terminology, dynamical-systems

For use in proving the independence of x for a functions rotation number. (think its because its Homeomorphic)

Comment: Do you mean the property in which $x\lt y$ implies $f(x) \lt f(y)$?  If so please edit your post so you you aren't mixing up X with x and Y with y.

Comment: yeah that's what i meant. i'm essentially trying to show $| F^n(x) - F^n(y) | \leq k $ in a orientation-preserving homeomorphism  where $k,n \in N$

Answer (score 3):

A function with the property $x < y \Rightarrow f(x) < f(y) $ can be called $\textbf{strictly monotone increasing}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would call a function that obeys $x < y \to f(x) < f(y)$ for all $x,y$, a *strictly increasing* function.